# sip client на spring web

Tags: java, asterisk, sip

Кто может поделиться информацией как внедрить sip клиента в spring web приложение.

У меня имеется:

1. sip server на базе астериск, с оборудованием, через которое совершаются вызовы на номера мобильных операторов;
2. веб страничка, на которой пользователь должен ввести номер и нажать "совершить вызов".

Попрошу не бить ногами, а подсказать, какие технологии/библиотеки можно использовать как на фронте, так и на бэкенд, чтобы совершить звонок из веб приложения, что можно почитать, чтобы углубиться в данный вопрос.
Ps. попрошу не отправляйте меня учить протокол sip. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основные шаги:

1. Необходимо настроить Asterisk для работы с **WebRTC** клиентами(pjsip + ssl + wss):
   [wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Configuring+Asterisk+for+WebRTC+Clients)
   **примечание**: используйте для удобства конфиг pjsip_wizard.conf, ssl от letsencrypt, кодек **opus** не использовать(качество голоса падает)
2. Выбрать библиотеку для работы с SIP протоколом по WEB, к примеру(мой выбор!), [JsSIP](https://github.com/versatica/JsSIP)
3. Реализовать свой web софтфон используя библиотеку(у меня написан на Vue.js), образец:

[image: пример web софтфона]

**Проблемы:** в Windows 10 иногда блокируется доступ к медиа устройствам.

Задавайте вопросы, я буду дополнять. Тут много нюансов.